# Selma map List<T> to T

Tags: java, mapping, object-object-mapping

I am using Selma and I have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date registeredDate;
    private List<Address> addresses;

}
```

I want to map it to:

```
public class Customer
{
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date registeredDate;
    private String company;
    private Address address1;
    private Address address2;
}
```

Is there any way to cast the (int) `id` to (String) `id` and to set the first address from the `List` to `address1` and the second address to `address2`?

I was thinking of using an interceptor, but this way I will have to manually map the `Address` classes. Is there a way to use Selma to automatically map the address classes in the interceptor? For example:

```
 public class CustomerCustomMapper
{
    public void interceptMyCustomerToCustomer(com.mycode.domain.Customer source, Customer destination) {

        if(source.getAddresses() != null && source.getAddresses().size() > 0)
        {
            com.mycode.domain.Address myAddress1 = source.getAddresses().get(0);

            AddressMapper addressMapper = Selma.builder(AddressMapper.class).build();

            Address address1 = addressMapper.mapAddress(myAddress1);
            destination.setAddress1(address1);

           // do the same for address2
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

Regarding mapping the Address class I did it the way I showed above. I created an `AddressMapper` with the following code inside: `Address toAddress(com.mycode.domain.Address address);`

Then I created an addressMapper and used it to map the Address autimatically:

```
AddressMapper addressMapper = Selma.builder(AddressMapper.class).build();
```

As for the id, currently I have to create an interceptor for every class that I map (almost every class has an Id in it (SQL)), and manually set the id like so: `destination.setId(Integer.toString(source.getId()));`

It is quite frustrating actually, but sadly I can't find a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the list to Address the interceptor is the good answer.

For the int to String you can specify a custom mapper mapping from int to String (see http://www.selma-java.org/#custom-mapper).

But I would recommend using an abstract mapper instead of building a new mapper to map the Address. This way you'll be able to integrate your specific code inside the mapper and call the address mapper method directly (see http://www.selma-java.org/#abstract-mapper).

For the toString thing, you can also add a feature request to Github. I'll be glad to add this feature.